# Slide navigation with Sencha Touch 2 and Ibm Worklight

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using this tutorial to create a slide navigation using sencha touch

http://innofied.com/simplest-slide-navigation-with-sencha-touch-2-2/

When implementing this in ibm worklight i dont know how to use app.js in  worklight

THE app.js :

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'SlideNav',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],

    views: [
                                'Viewport',
        'Main',
                                'Navigation'
    ],

                controllers : ['App'],

    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('SlideNav.view.Viewport'));
    },

    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
            function(buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

On worklight we have one main file that we use to initiate the app :

main.js:

```
window.$ = WLJQ;

function wlCommonInit(){
    initializeSenchaApp();
}

function initializeSenchaApp(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Initializing Sencha Touch code");

    Ext.application({
        name: 'Ersal',
        views: ['Login','Home'],
        controllers: ['Login'],

        launch: function () {

            Ext.Viewport.add([
                { xtype: 'loginview' },
                { xtype: 'mainmenuview' }
            ]);
            //Ext.create('Ersal.view.Login');
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to work with the app.js. You can only edit your main.js and add your medels, controllers and views.

Here is the code:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    initializeSenchaApp();
}

function initializeSenchaApp(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Initializing Sencha Touch code");

    Ext.application({
        name: 'YouApp',
        requires: ['Ext.Menu', 'YouApp.components.MenuButton'],
        views: ['Home'],
        models: ['Movie'],
        controllers: ['Home'],

        launch: function () {
            Ext.getBody().removeCls('loading');

            Ext.Viewport.add([
                { xtype: 'mainmenuview' },
            ]);
        }
    });

}
```

Wish it helps

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily to create a separate `app.js` file, it is sufficient to use an existing `main.js` file.

If you want to include sencha plug-in in your application you have to set the loader path in `main.js` file as like this:

```js
Ext.Loader.setPath({
      'Ext.ux':'ux'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the content of App.js in main.js, you have to load app.js before main.js in your HTML file, so make sure the ordering is correct. If it says that Ext is undefined, it probably is because you have the <script> tag that loads main.js before the one for App.js, so if that is the case, switch them around.